# How to calculate exp function of complex number $e^{a+bi}$

Tags: complex-numbers

In JavaScript there is function `Math.exp` that do $e^x$. I need to calculate the same but for complex numbers (for my [Scheme based lips interpreter in JavaScript](https://lips.js.org/)).

I think that this should be calculate like this (correct me if I'm wrong):

I have $a+bi$ (in my code I have `im` and `re` parts of a number).

To get $\Phi$ and $r$ I can just use my functions that I've already implemented `angle` and `magnitude` that just do:

$\Phi = atan2(im, re), r = \sqrt{im^2+re^2}$

I can use exponential form of $z$ and use it with $e^z$

$z=e^{r*e^{i\Phi}}$

$z=e^{r*e+i\Phi}$

But I'm not sure what to do next. I need to calculate normal form $a+bi$ of the result.

Comment: You can use Euler's formula: $$e^{a+ ib}=e^a (\cos(b)+i \sin(b)).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason for you to try to express $a+bi$ in polar form. Just use the fact that$$e^{a+bi}=e^a\bigl(\cos(b)+\sin(b)i\bigr).$$